# How to add direction indicator in google map v2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]

I want to add this direction indicator in my map, this is my coode for enable this indicator, but it not displayed yet.

```
UiSettings mUiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
mUiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);
```

Comment: -  can You help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962588/how-to-move-existing-the-markers-from-one-position-to-another-with-animation?noredirect=1&lq=1       U got something regarding this? I need this type of features Please Help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though you enable compass in settings, the direction compass will be visible only after you change the bearing of the map from the default. So if you have enabled touch gestures, then you can rotate the map with your fingers to changed the bearing and you will start seeing the compass

Comment: hi is there any option that this indicator move automatically to the direction?