# How to move existing the markers from one position to another with animation

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer, android-maps-utils

I am tracking my employees position on google map what I want to do is
to move the marker from its old position to a new position.
I am using [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) library for the cluster marker and the custom marker icons.

I want to move the marker from one position to another one, like other apps move their icons like any online cab application

Please help me, it's very important for me.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with question ? Why people are doing negative mark for such as good question.

Comment: @XYZ U got something related to fulfill your Requirement ? please share detail i also need type of features

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the Marker along with the user interactions on the map something like few Cab Service do, you can refer the below link for the solution :

[Map style like other Cab Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27504607/3458008)

Comment: Can you explain your requirement a little more ?

Comment: yes for sure..........

As  i have mentioned above i am tracking my employee current location and showing it on admin module of application and updating the markers in real time. i want the marker to move from one position to another as employee moves, to display custom markers and clustered markers i have the android map utility library.